# Variance of the difference of two random variables

Tags: random-variables

I have the following problem:
Suppose an unbiased coin is tossed 10 times. Let D be the random
variable that denotes the number of heads minus the number of tails.
What is the variance of D?

My solution is: Let X be the number of heads and Y be the number of tails, so $X~Bin(10,\frac{1}{2})$ and $Y~Bin(10,\frac{1}{2})$ and $D=X-Y$

Now $Var(D)=Var(X)+Var(Y)-2COV(X,Y)$ but since X and Y are Independent we have that covariance will be 0 i.e, $COV(X,Y)=0$

so $Var(D)=Var(X)+Var(Y)=2np(1-p)=2\cdot10\cdot\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2})=5$

Where am i wrong in this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. In fact, $Y=10-X$.

Comment: Hint. Try defining $X_i=1$ if toss $i$ is a head and $-1$ if it's a tail.

Comment: Given $n$ tosses, heads + tails = $n$, so the number of heads AND number of tails cannot be independent variables, given $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $X+Y=10$. So $D=X-Y=X-(10-X)=2X-10$.  This gives $var (D)=4 var (X)$.
So $Var(D)=4\cdot np(1-p)=4\cdot 10\cdot \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2})=10$.

Comment: thank you @geetha290krm